# How to add/remove rows using SlickGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

How to write such functions and bind them to two buttons like "add row" and "remove row":

The now working example code only support adding new row by editing on the blank bottom line.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <title>SlickGrid example 3: Editing</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../slick.grid.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="examples.css" type="text/css"/>
  <style>
    .cell-title {
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .cell-effort-driven {
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="position:relative">
  <div style="width:600px;">
    <div id="myGrid" style="width:100%;height:500px;"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="options-panel">
    <h2>Demonstrates:</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>adding basic keyboard navigation and editing</li>
      <li>custom editors and validators</li>
      <li>auto-edit settings</li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Options:</h2>
    <button onclick="grid.setOptions({autoEdit:true})">Auto-edit ON</button>
    &nbsp;
    <button onclick="grid.setOptions({autoEdit:false})">Auto-edit OFF</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="../lib/firebugx.js"></script>

<script src="../lib/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/jquery.event.drag-2.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="../slick.core.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/slick.cellrangedecorator.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/slick.cellrangeselector.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/slick.cellselectionmodel.js"></script>
<script src="../slick.formatters.js"></script>
<script src="../slick.editors.js"></script>
<script src="../slick.grid.js"></script>

<script>
  function requiredFieldValidator(value) {
    if (value == null || value == undefined || !value.length) {
      return {valid: false, msg: "This is a required field"};
    } else {
      return {valid: true, msg: null};
    }
  }

  var grid;
  var data = [];
  var columns = [
    {id: "title", name: "Title", field: "title", width: 120, cssClass: "cell-title", editor: Slick.Editors.Text, validator: requiredFieldValidator},
    {id: "desc", name: "Description", field: "description", width: 100, editor: Slick.Editors.LongText},
    {id: "duration", name: "Duration", field: "duration", editor: Slick.Editors.Text},
    {id: "%", name: "% Complete", field: "percentComplete", width: 80, resizable: false, formatter: Slick.Formatters.PercentCompleteBar, editor: Slick.Editors.PercentComplete},
    {id: "start", name: "Start", field: "start", minWidth: 60, editor: Slick.Editors.Date},
    {id: "finish", name: "Finish", field: "finish", minWidth: 60, editor: Slick.Editors.Date},
    {id: "effort-driven", name: "Effort Driven", width: 80, minWidth: 20, maxWidth: 80, cssClass: "cell-effort-driven", field: "effortDriven", formatter: Slick.Formatters.Checkmark, editor: Slick.Editors.Checkbox}
  ];
  var options = {
    editable: true,
    enableAddRow: true,
    enableCellNavigation: true,
    asyncEditorLoading: false,
    autoEdit: false
  };

  $(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
      var d = (data[i] = {});

      d["title"] = "Task " + i;
      d["description"] = "This is a sample task description.\n  It can be multiline";
      d["duration"] = "5 days";
      d["percentComplete"] = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
      d["start"] = "01/01/2009";
      d["finish"] = "01/05/2009";
      d["effortDriven"] = (i % 5 == 0);
    }

    grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);

    grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.CellSelectionModel());

    grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe(function (e, args) {
      var item = args.item;
      grid.invalidateRow(data.length);
      data.push(item);
      grid.updateRowCount();
      grid.render();
    });
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually I figured it out myself. Please let me know if you have any better idea on how to do this.

```
$("#add_row").click(function() {
  var dd = grid.getData();
  dd.splice(dd.length,0,{"title":""});
  grid.invalidateRow(data.length);
  grid.updateRowCount();
  grid.render();
  grid.scrollRowIntoView(dd.length-1)
})

$("#remove_row").click(function() {
  var dd = grid.getData();
  var current_row = grid.getActiveCell().row;
  dd.splice(current_row,1);
  var r = current_row;
  while (r<dd.length){
    grid.invalidateRow(r);
    r++;
  }
  grid.updateRowCount();
  grid.render();
  grid.scrollRowIntoView(current_row-1)
})
```

Answer (score 8):

Use **grid.invalidateAllRows()** instead of *grid.invalidateRow()* looping.

Answer (score 3):

Well it's kind of the same thing you've done, but slightly different cause I don't re-render.

Take a look at the following:

```
            var data= grid.getData();
            var rows= grid.getSelectedRows();

            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i += 1) {
                data.splice(rows[i], 1);
            }
            grid.setData(data, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in more simple way by using insertItem and deleteItem of DataView.

```
function add_new_row(){
 item = {
      "id": (Math.round(Math.random()*-10000))
    };
 data_view.insertItem(0, item);
}

function delete_row(e, args){
 var selectedrows = grid.getSelectedRows();  
 var len = selectedrows.length;
 var sure= confirm("Are You Sure You Want to Delete?");   
 if(sure){
  for(var i=0;i<len;i++){                        
   var data = grid.getData().getItem(selectedrows[i]);                         
   data_view.deleteItem(data.id)                                                 
  }
 }
}
```

Then, bind with the buttons.

```
<button onclick="add_new_row()">ADD</button>
<button onclick="delete_row()">DELETE</button>
```